# Throwing custom exception in (Drools)

Tags: java, drools

Do we have a possibility to **throw our custom exception in drools**?

So, I have some rule and need to throw my custom exception with important data.

**Drools Rule:**

```
import com.statest.aifmd.etl.validator.data.ValidationException 

  rule "Linking Rule"

  when   
      $dictionary: Dictionary()
      $fileName: String()   
  then   
      queryFundMasterTable("String", $dictionary, $fileName);
  end


  function void queryFundMasterTable(String sourceFieldName Dictionary dictionary, String fileName) {  

     String result = dictionary.findRecord(sourceFieldName);  
     if ((result == null) || result.isEmpty()) { 

            throw new ValidationException(new ValidationMessage(fileName, Level.WARNING));

     }   
  }
```

**Java:**

```
public void process(ExtractRow row, ValidRecord validRecord, String extractFilename) throws ValidationException {      
            session.execute(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { filename, dictionary}));

}
```

Comment: For what I remember, Drools will wrap the exception thrown into a different one. So in your `process` method you'll need to catch the drools exception and take from it the instance of `ValidationException`.

Comment: It would be better to do that validation in the rules and insert a rejection fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. You'll have to try and catch the fireAllRules call, expecting a org.drools.runtime.rule.ConsequenceException wrapping your custom exception.

But it's a rather uncouth way of exiting from the Engine, and it should never, NEVER be used to indicate a regular or even unusual flow of control. If, however, your ValidationException will lead to a graceful shutdown, then it's OK.